# how to fix 'confliction between file system and mysql database'

Tags: mysql, node.js

My nodejs program has 2 functions:

1. save some data to database (mysql): **foo1()**
2. read some other data from an existing file: **foo2()**

I realize when I run foo1() before foo2(), the saving into database part will be working fine. However, if I put foo1() after foo2(), the data will never be saved into database. Here is some codes.

I understand it is async, so I put foo1() in the 'end'. If I run it this way, foo1() seems to be executed, but it is not saving into mysql. However, if I put foo1() before point A, it gets saved. If I put foo1() after point B, it will not save data into database, but I can see it is running in foo1() when I use step-by-step mode in vs code...

**This is my foo2().**

```
//this is my foo2.
//point A
fs.createReadStream(file_location)
    .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ':' }))
    .on('data', function (csvrow) {
        input_data.push(parseFloat(csvrow[0]));
    })
    .on('end', function () {   //ensure my_update() is executed after done reading the file, so my_update() can use data from the file.
        my_update();  //foo1() is in my_update()
    });

//point B
```

**and this is foo1()**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var save_to_db = function (best_nn, fitness, type) {

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'nodejstestdb'
    });
    connection.connect();

    var string_nn = JSON.stringify(best_nn.toJSON());

    var addSql = 'INSERT INTO mytable1(nn, type, fitness) VALUES(?,?,?)';
    var addSqlParams = [string_nn, type, fitness];

    connection.query(addSql, addSqlParams, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('[INSERT ERROR] - ', err.message);
            return;
        }

        console.log('--------------------------INSERT----------------------------');
        //console.log('INSERT ID:',result.insertId);        
        console.log('INSERT ID:', result);
        console.log('-----------------------------------------------------------------\n\n');
    });

    connection.end();
}
```

ie

```
if save_to_db() is here, it is OK.
//this is my foo2.
//point A
fs.createReadStream(file_location)
    .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ':' }))
    .on('data', function (csvrow) {
        input_data.push(parseFloat(csvrow[0]));
    })
    .on('end', function () {   //ensure my_update() is executed after done reading the file, so my_update() can use data from the file.
        my_update();  //foo1() is in my_update()
    });

//point B

but if save_to_db() is here, it will save to db.
```